# Request working in curl but not in postman

Tags: curl, postman

This request working with curl

```
curl 'http://www.express.com/browse/gadgets/store-change-location-more.jsp?changelocation=true&catelogRefId=75116576' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=6D26018EFF8B54EC4022299B2AC7B184.cmhlpecomecm02w2;' --compressed
```

But the same request not working in post man

Post man request

```
Request Type : GET

URL : http://www.express.com/browse/gadgets/store-change-location-more.jsp?changelocation=true&catelogRefId=75116576

Headers:

Cookie: JSESSIONID=6D26018EFF8B54EC4022299B2AC7B184.cmhlpecomecm02w2;
```

How to make request work with post man too?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having same problem now and @ennovation's answer didn't resolve.

Answer (score 12):

Intermittently happened to me as well. I tried these steps:

- Go to settings, disable Send Postman Token Header
- Disable Interceptor (The satellite icon at the top)

Not sure why, but it simply worked!

Comment: It is not working for me. Did anyone got the solution for this question?

Comment: Try to also get rid of any Cookie that may have been sitting there.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, only the requests to localhost were working. This happened after it synchronized with other instances I was logged into.

After I disabled **SSL certificate verification** in Settings->General, it started working again.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was a newline at the end of url in Postman. There actually WAS a newline indicator in url bar, but it looked more like a dirt on the monitor so I missed it. Also the curl WAS in fact generated correctly, but I initially thought it is some issue regarding single or double quotas on Windows so I was changing them and also deleting the newline happily without thinking to make it work ...

Comment: Oh!  Thank you!! This was my problem too.

Comment: +1 I literally thought it was dirt on mine too, there was a tiny return symbol at the end of the URL and deleting it worked.

Comment: Oh my! what a life saver. I struggled for days. Thanks.

Comment: lifesaver. still works

Answer (score 5):

I had to make sure all the hidden auto-generated headers in postman were checked/enabled. I had initially disabled them which was causing this issue for me.

Comment: This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was accidentally added extra `/` e.g: www.test.com//endpoint in Postman address but when saving to CODE, Postman reformatted it and removed extra `/`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the request was failing because I was hitting an internal resource being served over HTTPS.  Disabling SSL Certificate Validation in the Postman preferences fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm running an HTTP process in localhost (port 8090)

The curl request generated by pressing the Code button in Postman works fine, returning the expected results i.e:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8090/tel-2/customers' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

When I attempt to run it through the GUI I get back an HTTP 400 with an HTML error response as follows (`<style>` section omitted for brevity).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

When I access the URL through the browser also works fine.

I have attempted to re-install Postman but the problem persists.
The Postman version that I'm using is Desktop 7.31.1, the latest at the moment.

Finally, I uninstalled Postman desktop completely and the older Chrome version 5.5.5 works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a proxy? I'm having a similar issue and I believe the issue is the handshaking protocol with the proxy not being applied to the postman application.

Comment: I was behind a proxy, and I had "Use the system proxy" checked, but also had "Add a custom proxy configuration checked". Once I unchecked "Add a custom proxy configuration", my requests started working. I imagine the "Add a custom proxy configuration" setting was overwriting my proxy environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

My problem isn't directly related to Postman but was in adding an extra `/` to end of REST resource, so I got 404. The solution is simply do not add extra space for 
the REST listing resource:

`example.com/api/items/` -> `example.com/api/items`

Comment: This answer doesn't seem relevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

One case not discussed yet: curl will attempt to use HTTP 2 where available, while Postman only supports HTTP 1.1.

I ran into an api that returned a 500 when the connection used 1.1, which meant the calls were working with curl but failing with postman.  When I passed the `--http1.1` flag to curl, it got the same response as Postman.

More generally, running curl in verbose mode (with the `-v` flag) can help you figure out what could be different between the two requests.

Answer (score 0):

My API request was taking around **4000ms** to return a response while timeout was set to **1000ms** in postman settings.

After I set *Settings->General->Request timeout in ms(0 for infinity)* to **0**, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was that I was trying to get oauth2 token, and had the `client-id` and `client-secret` as key-value pairs in the `x-www-form-urlencoded` section of the request `body`.

I kept getting an error saying

```
{
     "fault": {
         "faultstring":"Invalid client identifier {0}",
         "detail": {"errorcode":"oauth.v2.InvalidClientIdentifier"}
      }
}
```

The solution was to put credentials into the `raw` section of the request `body` instead, as follows:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=some-client-id&client_secret=some-client-secret
```

Got the token after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had an even sillyer issue!

The cURL created by chrome worked, but when I imported it into Postman it didn't.

Only I'd forgot to change the method type in postman to POST instead of GET